# Increasing and not bounded above implies all subsequences are not bounded above?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Suppose $(x_n)$ is an increasing sequence of real numbers and not bounded above. Is it true that all its subsequences are not bounded above?

I think the statement is not true. We can have an increasing sequence such that it has multiple limit points. For example, we can have a sequence $x_n=n$, but 'chop' by adding more terms such that it has $10$ and $11$ as limit points. Then we have two subsequences which are bounded above.

Question: Is my thinking process above correct? If yes, how should we obtain a closed for such a sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(b_n)$ a infinite subsequence of $(a_n)$. Suppose that $b_n$ is bounded above. Then there exists a $M$ such that for all $n$, $b_n$ is less than $M$. Since $a_n$ is unbounded, let $a_{n_1}$ be an element of the sequence $a_n$ that is greater than $M$. Then there exists $n_2>n_1$ such that $a_{n_2}$ is an element of $(b_n)$ ( otherwise the sequence $(b_n)$ is finite, which is obviously bounded)). But then the sequence $(b_n)$ has already exceeded $M$, a contradiction.

Sr for the form, I'm typing on a phone, will fix it later ;)

Answer (score 2):

no, an increasing sequence only has only limit point, which is either $\infty$ if the sequence is unbounded or $\sup_n x_n$ if the sequence if bounded.
If $x_n$ is an increasing sequence and $x_n=10$ for infinitely many $n$, then necessarily $x_n=10$ for all $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: I understand your argument, but I thought we can add increasing and bounded above subsequence without affect unboundedness of main sequence? For example, let $x_n = n$. Then I insert a another sequence $y_n = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ so that it has a bounded above and increasing subsequence.

Comment: @Idonknow but your $y_n$ sequence is not a subsequence of the original.

Comment: you cannot insert another subsequence. The resulting sequence will not be increasing anymore. An increasing sequence always has a limit (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) and so every subsequence must have the same limit

Comment: I understand my problem now. If we 'glue' two sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ as described as in my comment above, then one cannot go to $x_2$ since natural number will be exhausted. Unless we deal with ordinal, otherwise we cannot do it.